# Dagger2 - FragmentSubcomponentBuilder does not implement AndroidInjector.Factory

Tags: android, dependency-injection, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

I'm using dagger 2 and trying to translate my Android project from Java to Kotlin. After successful build i'm getting runtime error:

MyFragmentSubcomponentBuilder does not implement AndroidInjector.Factory

With Java this error not appeared. And also i noticed that in my module ActivityBuilder all methods are unused after build (they must be used in generated subcomponents classes).

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBuilder {

    // ...

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = arrayOf(MainActivityModule::class,MyFragmentProvider::class))
    internal abstract fun bindMainActivity(): MainActivity  // this method highlighted with gray color in AndroidStudio as unused 
}
```

How can i setup my project to use dagger 2 and kotlin correctly ?

my top level gradle.build:

```
 buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.51'
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
            mavenCentral()
            google()
            maven {
                url 'https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm/raw/master/maven-repo'
            }
            maven {
                url "https://jitpack.io"
            }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
            classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.0.0"
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        }
    }

    // ...
```

And app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    kapt {
        generateStubs = true
    }
}

// ...

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}

dependencies {

    // ...

    kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.0'

    //Dagger 2 dependencies
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.11'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.11'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.11'

    // ...
}
```

As you can see i not using annotationProcessor for dagger 2 (only kapt), and also i added generateStubs = true. But i still getting error in runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `AndroidSupportInjectionModule` in your array module in `ApplicationComponent`

For example

```
@Singleton
@Component(
        modules = arrayOf(
                AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
                ActivityBuilder::class,
                AppModule::class
        )
)
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<App> {

    @Component.Builder
    abstract class Builder : AndroidInjector.Builder<App>()

}
```